# Let me know when mail was NOT received to the mail (for successful DB backup for example)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I have a site I'm building and have a DB backup running on it several times a day.

Every successful backup is sent to my mail (and directed by a rule to a folder since there are many backups..) and every failure is also sent to me (not directed by a rule).

I'm afraid that the task will stop running from some reason and I will not know (no alerts arriving but how can I notice it in the blur of mails).

Is there a SW or process that alerts me when a mail was not received during a specific time?

The reason I'm asking here is that I want to develop this kind of thing (if does not exist).
Thanks

Comment: I have no code since I didn't write any yet. in fact I'm using phpmybackuppro that sends me notifications on DB backup. the issue is when these notifications are not sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know, unless you create something for yourself. E.g. a rule to auto-reply the received message (at receiver's mailbox). Your program (that sent the e-mail) should check his own mailbox within x seconds for the reply after sending.

Normally it is just a send and goodbye system, unless the e-mail box is full, unreachable, etc.

Comment: OK.. maybe I can do something like - writing to the DB every time I get mail. Then - on a separate process, sample the DB and check the last time a mail was received. if received too long a go - send a mail/SMS that alerts. can I do something like that?

Comment: That's an option as well. If you always keep the same receiver and know their mailbox credentials...

Comment: my solution sounds like an overkill to a simple request.. isn't there some generic solution? isn't this something any webmaster/developer would want? I get so many "DB backup OK" or "Process finished OK" alerts to the mail. how would I ever know if any one of them was not running at all? (without building this "monster" of course"